# In java, how do I check if a string contains only 1 or 0

Tags: java

Also, how would I prompt the user to try again until they enter something with only 1 or 0 in it?

I realize I must use a for, or a while loop, but I'm not sure what to put as the condition.

I'm trying to have it so the user is prompted to enter something in binary, and if they don't enter something in binary, to be asked again to enter something in binary, and repeated until they do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by a simple regular expression matching:

```
if (inputString.matches("^[01]+$")) {
    // accept this input
}
```

Comment: The hat and dollar are redundant.  Just "[01]+" is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `Integer.parseInt (str, 2);`

it will throw a `NumberFormatException` if not binary

Comment: It also throws that exception is the String is "too" long (for integer). ... if you define `11111111111111111111111111111111` "too long".

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect every character of the String like so:

```
String s;//user input
boolean bad=false;//Starts false-will change to true if the input is bad
for(char c:s.toCharArray())
    if(!(c=='0'||c=='1')){//if c isn't 0 or 1
       bad=true;
       break;//break out of loop because we've already found a problem
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what 'char c:s.toCharArray()' does?

Comment: This is needlessly complicated code for a simple task.

Comment: @KommanderKitten What this does is it iterates through every character in the String (The for loop literally says "for every character in s as a character array"), and compares them to '0' and '1'. If both comparisons fail (the character is neither '0' nor '1'), then it sets bad to true, meaning that the String is bad, then breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @ChthonicProject This is a 1 rep user who appears to be new to programming, so I didn't think regex was appropriate. My solution is written out pretty literally so that it can be easily understood.

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed new to programming, trying to learn bit by bit. However, I think you might have misunderstood my question. I want to break out of the loop if the string only contains 1s or 0s (a binary number), not if it contains anything else. If it contains something else (say, "no!") then it will repeat the prompt of "Enter a binary number". Does that make sense?

Comment: I've given you a code snippet that you can apply to your program; I only wrote it to demonstrate the concept of reading through the array. What you can do with this snippet is put it in your code, and break out of your loop if bad is true, or if you understand the concept, you can write a neater implementation. My break does not break out of your loop; it breaks out of my loop, in order to avoid unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the pattern below.  The concept is to provide a "regular expression" that provides the rules for a conforming string, along with the message to prompt the user for input and the source to read the user's input from.  The loop continues until a conforming string is found, or the user breaks out with "exit".  The function would return the conforming string, or a null if the user wants to exit.

```
public String getConformingString(Scanner source, String message, String pattern) {
  String result = null;
  boolean isConformingString = false;
  System.out.println(message);

  String trialString = source.mextLine();
  while (!isConformingString) {
    if (trialString.matches(pattern) {
      isConformingString = true;
      result = isConformingString;
    } else if ("exit".equalsIgnoreString(trialString)) {
      isConformingString = true;
    } else {
      System.out.println(message);
      trialString = source.nextline();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```